# Error creating token with Laravel Santum when tokenable morph uses UUIDs

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am having problems when generating tokens with laravel sanctum.
The error claims that the value is out of range for the column '**tokenable_id**'.

Here textual:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'c247a941-4954-4bf3-91eb-ddf37a8e2611' for column 'tokenable_id'

This is the error message (image):

[image]

In my user model, I have implemented the uuid as the primary key, so the id corresponds to this code: c247a941-4954-4bf3-91eb-ddf37a8e2611, which claims the error.

This is the function where I am creating the token:

###### LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

         /* Token generation */
        $plainTextToken = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([[
            'plain-text-token' => $plainTextToken
        ]);

    }
}
```

To my understanding, this uuid, is the one that is generating me the error, then , my question goes to what action should I implement to resolver with uuid with primary key.
Should I modify the personal tokens table, so that it accepts this string that is now the user id?

I remain attentive to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to update your personal_access_tokens table migration. Change morphs('tokenable') to uuidMorphs('tokenable'), since morphs() is used when your related model (users in this case) uses auto increment. Since you are using uuids, you have to make this change to support those values.

#### 1 - Make a migration

```
php artisan make:migration alter_tokenable_on_personal_access_tokens --table=personal_access_tokens
```

#### 2 - Copy this in

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Alter the personal_access_tokens so that the tokenable columns (which refer
 * to the user model) will work with UUIDs.
 */
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations. Needs to be in two steps so that the drop is
     * committed before adding the new ones.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropMorphs('tokenable');
        });
        Schema::table('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations. Needs to be in two steps again.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropMorphs('tokenable');
        });
        Schema::table('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->morphs('tokenable');
        });
    }
};
```

#### 3 - Run the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

`$user->createToken(...)` should now work with the UUIDs on your user model.

Comment: If you add some styling and before-after snippets this great answer will be even more readable :)

Comment: Thanks - this explained the problem to me. I have added examples based on what I then did.